# Can an electron stand in place of proton like a ghost standing in place of you?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, temperature, electrons, orbitals

The atomic orbital refers to the physical region where the electron can be calculated to be present, as defined by the particular mathematical form of the orbital [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital). The picture below shows the $1s$ orbital.

The picture seems to signify that electron can exist in the same place as the protons. Is this the case?

When the distance between proton and electron becomes $0$, the gravitational force becomes $\infty$ (considering limits). So, for the electron to escape from the proton, electron needs to have high velocity nearly $\infty$, which means temperature to be $\infty$. I don't think we have ever observed such a situation where we have a chunk of matter with $\infty$ temperature. This condition doesn't seem to allow electron to stand in place of proton, but the QM (if I am not wrong) says it is possible.

What do you say, is it possible for the ghostly electron to stand in the same place as the proton?

---

Picture credits: [Wikipedia-atomic orbital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Orbitals_table).
 [image: sorbital]

> 1s orbital

Comment: The magnetic interaction between electron and proton, will be much larger than the the gravitational one.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the probability for the electron to be found inside the nucleus is, for some atomic orbitals, non-zero. However, you must recall that these orbitals usually assume a *point charge* for the nucleus, and so they may not be a valid when you "zoom in" to the nucleus. Nevertheless, there's nothing inherently *wrong* with the electron being where the proton is - you say there'd be a problem with gravitation, but we do not know how gravitation really works at the quantum level, except that, as with all forces, you probably should think of it as a QFT interaction rather than a classical force just pulling or pushing particles apart - just like the electromagnetic force is quantumly the interaction with the EM gauge field, and not just the Coulomb law. And also, you'd have to think about that fact that the proton is really a mess of quarks and gluons inside, and this line of thought just gets messier and messier, showing that imagining the electron "inside" the proton is probably a bad idea in the first place.

In short, you first have to drop *all* the approximations we usually make, and then you'll find that such a thing as being "inside" another particle is not really possible, because we think that the fundamental particles are really *point-like* (when detected as *particles* by a position measurement, that is)

Don't apply classical thinking about escape velocities or forces to quantum interactions! For example, classically, the $\alpha$-particle in the $\alpha$-decay can almost never leave the nucleus due to a potential barrier, but nevertheless we observe that it does - thanks to it being at scales where quantum effects are relevent, and tunneling through barriers can occur *without a well-defined notion of movement through it*. It's really the same idea here - don't imagine the electron *moving* around/through the nucleus, the very notion of movement is ill-defined for such a quantum object.

Comment: +1 for this beautifully written answer. Lately I've been pretty busy with univ, but whenever I get to come back to SE, your posts are always part of my favorite reads ;)